# $\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}e^\left(1/x\right)=0$ ($\delta-\varepsilon$ definition)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, definition, epsilon-delta

$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0^{-}}e^\left(1/x\right)=0$ So I wrote the definition:
$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists \delta_{\varepsilon}$ such that if $x_{0}-\delta<x<x_{0}$ then $\left|f(x)-L\right|<\varepsilon$
So let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Choose $\delta=-\dfrac{1}{\ln(\varepsilon)}$ if $-\delta<x<0$ implies that $\left|e^\left(1/x\right)\right|<\varepsilon$. So did I make a mistake? Because when I take $\varepsilon=0.001$ I didn't get closer to $0$
$\varepsilon=0.001$ then $\delta=0.144$ then the interval is $0.144<x<0$. So for example if I take $0.140$ I can't even get closer to $0$. For instance: $e^\left(1/0.140\right)=1265.03...$

Comment: What did you do when you took $\varepsilon=0.001$ and didn't get closer to 0? I'm not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I'll edit for that

Comment: As $e^{1/x}>\varepsilon$ is equivalent $x>\frac{1}{\ln \varepsilon}$, then your choice is correct.

Comment: When you take $\epsilon=0.001$, you get $\delta\approx0.14$, and if $-\delta<x<0$ then $\exp(1/x)<\epsilon$ as required

Comment: So you say that we just want to be function smaller than epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that you took $0\lt x\lt \delta$, when you took $x=0.140$.

You should take $-\delta\lt x\lt 0$, and then your requirement will be satisfied.

E.g., $e^{1/-0.140}\approx0.00079<0.001$.

Comment: Yes I checked it again, when I calculate those I forgot to add minus sign my bad. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

If $\varepsilon\geqslant1$, any $\delta$ will do. Otherwise, you have\begin{align}\left|e^{1/x}\right|<\varepsilon&\iff e^{1/x}<\varepsilon\\&\iff\frac1x<\ln\varepsilon\\&\iff x>\frac1{\ln\varepsilon}.\end{align}So, take $\delta=-\frac1{\ln\varepsilon.}$

Comment: Oh I see, so I did it correct then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option:

Consider $y:=-x$ and limit $y \rightarrow 0^{+}$.

$|e^{-1/y}|=|\dfrac{1}{e^{1/y}}|=|\dfrac{1}{1+1/y....}|\le |y|.$

Choose $\delta=\epsilon.$